# Raspbian and .net core

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have a problem.

I have newest raspbian, and I have installed .net core 2.1 on it, well everything looks fine until i reboot pi.

After reboot .net core command stops to work and i have to add

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet 
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

then it will work.

Is there a way to make it permanent.

Comment: You can put those exports in /home/pi/.bashrc

Comment: Where do you have do add the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet 
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Install it globaly, so any user can use it.

Helpful if one of your programm need to be run with root (**sudo**) ...

Here is my python install script (Update urls as you need :p ):

```
import os
def install_net_core():
  print("Downloading .net core SDK 3.1 ...")
  os.system('wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/349f13f0-400e-476c-ba10-fe284b35b932/44a5863469051c5cf103129f1423ddb8/dotnet-sdk-3.1.102-linux-arm.tar.gz')

  print("Downloading Asp.net core runtime 3.1 ...")
  os.system('wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8ccacf09-e5eb-481b-a407-2398b08ac6ac/1cef921566cb9d1ca8c742c9c26a521c/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.2-linux-arm.tar.gz')


  print("Extracting archive to /usr/share/dotnet ...")
  os.system('sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet')
  print("Extracting dotnet-sdk ...")
  os.system('sudo tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.1.102-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet')
  print("Extracting aspnetcore-runtime ...")
  os.system('sudo tar zxf aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.2-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet')
  os.system('sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet')

  print("Removing archives ...")
  os.system('sudo rm -f dotnet-sdk-3.1.102-linux-arm.tar.gz')
  os.system('sudo rm -f aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.2-linux-arm.tar.gz')

  os.system('dotnet --info')
```